# App freezes when requesting access to addressbook

Tags: swift, abaddressbook, cncontact, abaddressbooksource

```
func getContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .notDetermined {
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if authorized {
                self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
            }
        } as! (Bool, Error?) -> Void)
    } else if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) == .authorized {
        self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
    }
}

func retrieveContactsWithStore(store: CNContactStore) {
    do {
        let groups = try store.groups(matching: nil)
        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier: groups[0].identifier)
        //let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("John")
        let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]

        let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        self.objects = contacts
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I was trying to retrieve contacts from address book, but whenever I go to the view calling getContacts(), the app freezes. It wouldn't proceed anymore, but it didn't crash either. I wonder what went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for the call to `requestAccess` isn't correct. The syntax for the completion handler isn't valid. You need this:

```
func getContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
    if status == .notDetermined {
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { (authorized: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if authorized {
                self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
            }
        })
    } else if status == .authorized {
        self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)
    }
}
```

Also note the change to use the `status` variable. This is cleaner and easier to read than calling `authorizationStatus` over and over. Call it once and then check the value over and over as needed.

Comment: this code has an error on else status == .authorized part, it says "fix it insert ","  "

Comment: Oops. I over edited. Add an `if` in there. See the update.

Comment: And one other typo - missed the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Dude what should I put in the parameter for this function?

let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInGroup(withIdentifier:       )

Comment: That's a completely different question. If you can't find a solution after doing an appropriate amount of research (reading the documentation and searching), then please post a new question specific to your new issue.